# Para travessão, "--" pode ser usado?

Tags: ortografia, pontuação

Eu estava jogando Red Dead Redemption II. No jogo, há o diário do protagonista e nele o personagem principal às vezes usava "--" (2 hifens) ao invés de "—" (travessão). Recentemente, vi também noutro lugar, mas não me lembro onde.

Eu gostaria de saber se está correto usar "--" (2 hifens) ao invés de "—" (travessão).

Exemplo:

> Eu gosto dele -- João, o chatonildo da escola -- mesmo ele sendo um facínora!

P.P. (post praecuntatum): "facínora", em Portugal, pode ser usado brincando também? E uma dica: para digitar meia-risca (–), digita Alt+0150 e para travessão (—), Alt+0151; não pode ser o Alt Gr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muitas situações na lingua portuguesa dependem do ambiente e essa é uma delas. Se você está em um local que exige que você siga a norma culta padrão, utilizar -- está totalmente errado, pois não é um sinal reconhecido pela lingua. No entanto, se tratando de um jogo, já que o objetivo desta frase era apenas passar uma informação para o jogador e este objetivo foi cumprido, não há qualquer problema.

Quanto ao "facínora", não tenho como responder a sua suposição, já que sou brasileiro. Deixo essa para algum português.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Por sinal, usei "digita" ao invés de "digite", porque estou usando o "tu"; então, "digite você/ele/ela" e "digita tu".

Comment: Isso de usar dois hífens para travessão é do inglês. Não se usa em português culto.